# Xamarin Forms view not scrolling when keyboard visible

Tags: xamarin, scroll, keyboard

I have a Xamarin Forms application with a registration form.  Whenever I click in a field and the soft keyboard is displayed, the view does not scroll.  I've seen other posts about this issue, but the solutions either did not work or caused errors.  This is true for both Android and iOS versions.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: is your view enclosed in a ScrollView?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay.I've tried it with and without.  No scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a few things I needed to do to get it to work.

First, when I added more entry fields I found it would scroll.  However, it still won't scroll enough to display the fields behind the keyboard.  To accomplish this, I had to add a large bottom margin to the last field.

Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: Hi. Do you have any other suggestion how to make it work without adding Margin to last field?